# Processing.runalg is working in qgis python console but not producing output when executed in cmd

Tags: qgis

This is my code :

```
import sys

from qgis.core import *

# Initialize QGIS Application
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\\ProgramFiles\\QGISBrighton\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis", True)
app = QgsApplication([], True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# Add the path to Processing framework
sys.path.append('C:\\Program Files\\QGIS Brighton\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins')

# Import and initialize Processing framework
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
import processing

#Convert Raster to vector

processing.runalg("modeler:vectorize","D:\\Extracted zip files\\LC_hd_global_2001.tif","15",'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Raster_to_vector2BAT.shp')
print 'Raster_to_VectorBAT run successful'
```

Comment: Clarifying: you're trying to do this in a Python shell, started up in a Windows cmd shell, right?

Comment: If you installed QGIS using the OSGeo4W installer, it comes with an **OSGeo4W** shell program which is probably easier to run QGIS scripts.